# bash creating html email shows wrong array value

Tags: html, bash

I have a bash script that grabs some values, its them in an array and then calls those array values in the html portion of the email (html table)

I check for the existence of an xml file for today:

```
if [ -f /home/scrptadmin/health/${node}/$(date +%F)*.xml ]; then
            #add parsing of files here later, for now simple file check
            #declare "bk_${node}="SUCCESS"
            bk[$i]='SUCCESS'
            echo ${bk[$i]}
    else
            bk[$i]='FAIL'
            echo ${bk[$i]}
    fi
```

I know that $bk[5] is getting populated with "FAIL" - the xml file is from 2013 and does not match todays date so $bk[5] get populated with "FAIL" (as expected):

```
     i=5
    + for node in '"${bkdir[@]}"'
    ++ ssh 178.215.139.120 ls -1td '/DRSSYSTEM/HORTA/PRESC2/*'
    ++ head -1
    + scp 178.215.139.120:/DRSSYSTEM/HORTA/PRESC2/2013-04-11-07-55-06_drfComponent.xml   /home/scrptadmin/health/PRESC2
    2013-04-11-07-55-06_drfComponent.xml                                       100%   49KB  48.5KB/s   00:00    
    ++ date +%F
    + '[' -f '/home/scrptadmin/health/PRESC2/2014-04-09*.xml' ']'
    + bk[$i]=FAIL
    + echo FAIL
    FAIL
```

However, when I go to use $bk[5] in the table:

```
<th scope=\"row\" style=\"background-color: rgb\(223, 223, 223\);\">Backup</th>
                                                                    <td>${bk[4]}</td>
                                                                    <td>${bk[5]}</td>
                                                                    <td>${bk[6]}</td>   
                                                    </tr>

   <th scope=\"row\" style=\"background-color: rgb\(223, 223, 223\);\">Backup</th>
                                                                    <td>SUCCESS</td>
                                                                    <td>SUCCESS</td>
                                                                    <td>SUCCESS</td>
                                                    </tr>
```

And it comes out in html as "SUCCESS"
I'm stumped as I'm using other elements of this array in this table and they are reflecting the array value correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround at least - If I put the array values into non-array variables it works correctly:

```
BK_CUP1=${bk[4]}
BK_CUP2=${bk[5]}
BK_CUP3=${bk[6]}

   <th scope=\"row\" style=\"background-color: rgb\(223, 223, 223\);\">Backup</th>
                                                                    <td>${BKCUC1A}</td>
                                                                    <td>${BKCUC2A}</td>
                                                                    <td>${BKCUC3A}</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                    <tr>
```